# Unable to install gem with the proxy option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation, ubuntu-12.04

Trying to solve this [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203632/could-not-find-a-valid-gem-rails-0-in-any-repository) I have a solution telling that using the [proxy](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:oAIJRRSLzooJ:docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/13%20&cd=1&hl=bg&ct=clnk&gl=bg) option when installing gem will help.

I am executing the following line:

```
sudo gem install rails --http-proxy=http://rubygems.org/
```

but it give me the same error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: rails
```

Could anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: just a thought, but you might try `sudo gem install rails -p 'http://rubygems.org'`

Comment: I have try, but the same error was thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP proxy isn't rubygems... if you espesify a proxy so... you have to put your own proxy... if you have not proxy... so don't put http-proxy... =)

Do first
REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM=1 sudo gem update --system

sudo gem install rails

Answer (score 1):

In both question -also question from - Ruby is installed by package managers like Synaptic, Aptitude. Debian-like operating systems stricts installation of gems without using package manager. You may use REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM with installation of gems like, but not recommended:

```
gem install rails REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM=true
```

Instead of that, you should prefer using [RVM](http://rvm.io) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) to get rid of package manager based installation

Comment: I have installed RVM. Then I typed: $rvm use 1.9.3 and $rvm install rails but it gives me the same error.